# i have 4 users the two other user cannot login not unless approve by the admin laravel

Tags: laravel

Hi I have 4 users which are the Admin Customer, pharmacy and carrier the one wh deliver the product.all three users need to register.After the register they go redirect to login .The two users need to approve by the admin in order to   login which is the carrier and pharmacy.

Here's what i have tried

In my database i have users table  which the customer, admin, carrier and pharmacy and has  "user_type" colum  and i have isapprove colum. 1 is approve and 0 if not approve.  so i set all users to zero .and my problem is i dnt know to make the pharmacy user not to login if the isapprove colum is 0.

Comment: have you set up middleware or potentially overloaded you LoginController?

Comment: Take a look at the docs [Specifying Additional Conditions](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#authenticating-users)

Answer (score 0):

In LoginController write

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    return Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password, 'isapprove' => 1 ]);
}
```

Comment: yes it work , i cannot login unless the status is 0. but i can only apply that in the 
  pharmacy and carrier. How to implement that ? that only the pharmacy and carrier has the status of o cannot login. only the pharmacy and carrier needs the update status

Comment: do you have any idea for this?

Comment: Can you please elaborate it ? I am not understanding your requirements. I am sure I can resolve your issue if you elaborate it.

Comment: what happen was   all the users like admin customer  pharmacy and carrier i set the default as zero in the isapprove colum  and  is fine for the pharmacy and carrier because they need to approve for the admin first to make the colum isapprove to 1. but my problem is the colum of the customer and the admin doesnt need to update for them to be able to login. only the pharmacy. how i am gonna  do it.  do i have to make another logon?

Comment: do you have an email? can i just email it to you?

Comment: Yes, send it to de.sumit11@gmail.com